# Can a Verifone Vx670 POS be programmed in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, point-of-sale, verifone

Disclaimer: I'm *very* new to the world of POS programming.

I need to do some programming of a Vx670 POS, and I would like to use C# to that end. After some goggling, I've found that there are generic converters from C# to C/C++, but since the POS architecture is rather limited, and the OS is a bit peculiar, I'm not sure that is a good path to follow.

So, I would like to know whether someone here, with experience in this endeavor, could shed some light on the matter for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could MS POS.NET have support for it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms828083(v=winembedded.10).aspx

Comment: Do you have an actual programming question?

Comment: @PeterM: what would you say this question is about? History of Art?

Comment: @kenny: in a forum in MS they say POS.NET is a framework to build the services to which the POS terminals connect to. This is consistent with what the page you've referred to:

_The class library provides .NET applications with a simple and consistent interface for communicating with Point of Service (POS) peripheral devices, such as bar code scanners, magnetic card readers, receipt printers, and so on._

Comment: @BrunoUnna not sure if you're asking anything, but it provides wrappers to handle a lot of similar POS devices in the same way. I imagine your Vx670 is handled by the category it fits into. How your POS app works is your value add, the framework fills in support for lots of hardware.

Comment: @BrunoUnna I refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and then we can talk about your penchant for non-sequiturs

Comment: @PeterM Very enlightening, thank you! From your referenced page:
_We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!_

The question is clearly programming related. Can a Vx670 be programmed in C#, or not? Not a non-sequitur: Do you know the answer, or not?

Comment: @kenny Thank you, but it seems (http://bit.ly/1lNvdmr) that POS for .NET is useful if you are creating your own POS, and intend to use attached peripherals. If your POS intelligence resides in a rather ordinary PC. But the problem at hand is different: I already have the POS, the ARM processor, the OS (Verix).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, to write software for Vx670 you will need the verifone Verix V development kit from Verifone. Then as long as converting code from C# to C++ and us there, depend on the natural of the code and if it depend on any specific hardware/software which may or may not be available on the Vx670.

Comment: I would like to point out, however, that you can use Visual Studio via MS Build, so you can at least keep your IDE.